# How to bind the Publisher of ObservableObject by SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I don't know how to bind Publisher in ObservableObject class on view file.

User

```
struct User: Identifiable,Decodable{
    var id: String?
    var email: String
    var username: String
    
}
```

ViewModel

```
class UserProfileViewModel: ObservableObject{
   @Published var user: User?

   //fetch data and bind the user property
}
```

UserProfile

```
struct UserProfile: View {  
    @ObservedObject private var userProfileVM = UserProfileViewModel()
     var body: some View {
        VStack{
       UserForm(name: Binding($userProfileVM.user.username)!, 
               email: Binding($userProfileVM.user.email)!
            )               }
     }
}
```

UserForm

```
struct UserForm: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    @Binding var email: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $name)
                    .keyboardType(.namePhonePad)
        TextField("email", text: $email)
    }
}
```

I don't know how to bind `userProfileVM.user.username` and `userProfileVM.user.email` in UserProfile on UserForm.
Now I got the errors `Value of optional type 'User?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'email' of wrapped base type 'User' & Chain the optional using '?' to access member 'email' only for non-'nil' base values` in UserProfile.

Please how to resolve it.

Comment: Do not say things like `Binding($userProfileVM.user.username)!`.

Comment: How should I modify it?

Comment: How to use `@Binding`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper

Comment: But you should not be using binding at all here. Just share your observable right into your view.

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't need view model objects, the View struct is already the view model. @ObservedObject should not init an object.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you are using `!` there is something incorrect. It should be very rare.

You need to check if the `@Published var user: User?` is not `nil`.

```
struct UserProfile: View {
    //StateObject is for initializing ObservedObject is for passng around.
    @StateObject private var userProfileVM = UserProfileViewModel()
     var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if let userB = Binding($userProfileVM.user){
                //Check if there is a user.
                UserForm(name: userB.username,  email: userB.email)
            }else{
                //Show/do something if there isn't
                ProgressView()
                    .task{
                        //Load user somehow...
                    }
            }
        }
     }
}
```